# Frontend Redirect in Express.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, redirect

I'm making a little bit complex page using `EJS` and `Express.JS`. I'll simplify it a little:

First application loads `/update` the easy way and renders it:

```js
app.get('/update', (req, res) => {
  res.render('update');
});
```

`update` in `render` function is an `EJS` template. Here's how it looks like:

```html
...
<div id="progress"></div>
<button id="perform" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Download & Update</button>
<script>
  $('#perform').click(function() {
    $('#perform').hide();
    $('#progress').load('/perform');
  });
</script>
...
```

As you can see on button click, application loads `/perform` `express.js` route into specific `div`. Here's what it does on `Node.JS` side:

```js
app.get('/perform', function(req, res) {
  //Renders div
  res.render('perform')
  
  //Does some actions in 1-2 minues.
  
  //Here I want it to redirect to / of application.
});
```

After it returns some content using `res.render()`, application starts doing some processes. They take about 1 minute and after completion I want application to redirect to `/`. I've tried using `res.redirect('/')` e.t.c., but nothing works. Maybe somehow it should tell browser to redirect..

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

You load "/perform" via ajax, so you can only send a response (which you do with the res.render('perform'))

So you should do the redirect client side

You can do this with polling, a timeout or even better, you could use socket.io to give a signal from server to client when the actions are done.